# How to print a 2D list so that each list is on a new line with a space, without any "" or []

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

I'm having trouble printing a list in a visually appealing manor.
An example of the list is

```
[["-", "-", "-", "-"],["-", "-", "-", "-"],["-", "-", "-", "-"]]
```

(the characters won't all necessarily be the same), but I need to print it without using any functions except `print`, `range`, `len`, `insert`, `append`, `pop`, and I cannot use any dictionaries or maps, or import any libraries or use any list-comprehensions. I in turn want:

```
- - - -
- - - - 
- - - -
```

I tried:

```
def print_board(board): 
    for i in board: 
        row = board[i] 
        for r in row: 
            print(*row[r], "\n")
```

Comment: is `print` allowed ?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: " I need to print it without using any functions except range, len, insert, append, pop": exactly the thing you're _not_ supposed to do when you want a good python code...

Comment: Since you're not allowed to use the `print()` function, you're gonna have a bad time with this one.

Comment: print is allowed. yes, it's a homework question, but it's not marked, i just really don't know how to proceed. i tried def print_board(board):
 for i in board:
  row = board[i]
  for r in row:
   print(*row[r], "\n")

Comment: psst... Your example list is missing some commas.

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: yes, i am using python 3.

Answer (score 5):

You're close, but you misunderstand how `for i in <list>` works. The iteration variable gets the list elements, not their indexes.

Also, `row[r]` (if `r` were the index) would be just a single string, not a list, so you don't need to unpack it with `*row[r]`.

There's no need to include `"\n"` in the `print()` call, since it ends the output with a newline by default -- you would have to override that with the `end=""` option to prevent it.

```
for row in board:
    for col in row:
        print(col, end=" ") # print each element separated by space
    print() # Add newline
```

Answer (score 1):

```
board = [["-", "-", "-", "-"],["-", "-", "-", "-"],["-", "-", "-", "-"]] 

for row in board:
    print(*row)
```

This is the easiest way, but relies on argument unpacking (that `*` star before the `row`).  If you can't use that for whatever reason then you can use the keyword arguments to `print` to achieve the same result

```
for row in board:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell, end=' ')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

With better named variables this migh lead to better understanding:

```
def print_board(board): 
    for innerList in board: 
        for elem in innerList: 
            print(elem + " ", end ='') # no \n after print
        print("") # now \n


b = [["-"]*4]*4       
print_board(b)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
- - - -  
- - - -  
- - - -  
- - - -  

[['-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-', '-']]
```